# Is there a syntax in the second function?

Tags: javascript

None of the code below runs unless I comment out the second function (findPalindromes()) entirely and I can't for the life of me figure why. Can someone help me look for errors in it?

This code is supposed to find a bunch of primes and then list primes that are also palindromes

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var low;
        var high;
        var primes=[];
        var pprimes=[];
        var div1;
        var div2;

            function findPrimes(){
                low=0;
                high=999;

                div1=document.getElementById("primes");
                if(low<0||high<=0||high<=low){
                    return;
                }

                for(var i=low; i<high; i++){
                    if(i<=2&&i!=0){ 
                        primes[primes.length]=i;

                        continue;
                    }

                    var isPrime;
                    for(var j=2; j<i;j+=2){
                        isPrime=true;
                        if((i%j)==0){
                            isPrime=false;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(j==2)
                            j++;
                    }
                    if(isPrime==true)
                        primes[primes.length]=i;
                }

                for(var i=0; i<primes.length; i++)
                    div1.innerHTML+=(primes[i]+" ");

                findPalindromes();
            }

            function findPalindromes(){
                for(var i=0; i<primes.length; i++){
                    if(primes[i]<10)
                        continue;

                    str=primes[i].toString();
                    isPal=true;
                    for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++){
                        if(str.charAt(j)!=str.charAt(str.length-j){
                            isPal=false;
                            break;
                        }
                        if((str.length-j)<=1)
                            break;
                    }
                    if(isPal==true)
                        pprimes[pprimes.length]=primes[i];
                }
                div2=document.getElementById("pprimes");

                for(var i=0; i<pprimes.length;i++){
                    div2.innerHTML+=(pprimes[i]+" ");
                }
            }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="findPrimes()">
<div id="primes"></div>
<div id="pprimes"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting (you can see errors in your browser console).

Comment: missing a closing bracket from if(str.charAt(j)!=str.charAt(str.length-j)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript doesn't use strongly-typed variables, it's weakly typed, there is no `int`, which you would have discovered by opening the console

```
for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++){
```

should be

```
for(var j=0;j<str.length;j++){
```

The same for loop has missing closing parenthesis for `charAt`

```
if (str.charAt(j) != str.charAt(str.length - j ) {
```

should be

```
if (str.charAt(j) != str.charAt(str.length - j) ) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm new to javascript and wasn't aware of the error log in the console. These things slip by sometimes.